# How to change color of text based on value via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

I am trying to change the color of my text based on the 'voltage drop' value. Ideally i want it to be red for a voltage drop of higher than 3% and green if lower.

Here is my current HTML:

```js
function printAnswer() {
    var volts = document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_volts")[0].value;
    var amps = document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_amps")[0].value;
    var length = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_m")[0].value);
    var cableSize = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_cableSize")[0].value);
    var ohm = 0;
    var reactance = 0;
    if (cableSize === 630) {
        ohm = 0.0418;
        reactance = 0.08;
    } else if (cableSize === 500) {
        ohm = 0.0506, reactance = 0.082;
    } else if (cableSize === 400) {
        ohm = 0.062;
        reactance = 0.0829;
    } else if (cableSize === 300) {
        ohm = 0.077;
        reactance = 0.0839;
    } else if (cableSize === 240) {
        ohm = 0.0948;
        reactance = 0.0847;
    } else if (cableSize === 185) {
        ohm = 0.123;
        reactance = 0.0862;
    } else if (cableSize === 150) {
        ohm = 0.153;
        reactance = 0.0868;
    } else if (cableSize === 120) {
        ohm = 0.188;
        reactance = 0.087;
    } else if (cableSize === 95) {
        ohm = 0.236;
        reactance = 0.0904;
    } else if (cableSize === 70) {
        ohm = 0.327;
        reactance = 0.0917;
    } else if (cableSize === 50) {
        ohm = 0.471;
        reactance = 0.0962;
    } else if (cableSize === 35) {
        ohm = 0.638;
        reactance = 0.101;
    } else if (cableSize === 25) {
        ohm = 0.884;
        reactance = 0.106;
    } else if (cableSize === 16) {
        ohm = 1.4;
        reactance = 0.111;
    } else if (cableSize === 10) {
        ohm = 2.23;
        reactance = 0.118;
    } else if (cableSize === 6) {
        ohm = 3.75;
        reactance = 0.128;
    } else if (cableSize === 4) {
        ohm = 5.61;
        reactance = 0.137;
    } else if (cableSize === 2.5) {
        ohm = 9.01;
        reactance = 0.143;
    } else if (cableSize === 1.5) {
        ohm = 16.5;
        reactance = 0.157;
    } else {
        msg = "Error";
    }
    var reactanceT = (reactance * length) / 1000;
    var ohmT = (ohm * length) / 1000;

    if (volts < 400) {
        var vDrop = ((ohm * 2) * (length / 1000) * amps);
    } else {
        var vDrop = (Math.sqrt(3)) * amps * (Math.sqrt((Math.pow(ohmT, 2)) + (Math.pow(reactanceT, 2))));
    }


    var vFinal = (volts - vDrop);
    var vDropPercent = ((vDrop / volts) * 100);
    console.log(volts, amps, length, cableSize, ohm);
    document.getElementById("vFinal").innerHTML = vFinal.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("vDrop").innerHTML = vDrop.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("vDropPercent").innerHTML = vDropPercent.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("resistanceCheck").innerHTML = ohmT.toFixed(4);
    document.getElementById("reactanceCheck").innerHTML = reactanceT.toFixed(4);
    
    if (vDropPercent > 3) {

        document.getElementsByName("results-box1").style.color = 'red';
    } else {
        document.getElementsByName("results-box1").style.color = 'green';
    }

}
```

```html
<p>Final Voltage (V)</p>
                <div class="results-box">
                    <p id="vFinal" style="margin: 10px 0;">&nbsp;</p>
                </div>

                <p>Voltage Drop (V)</p>
                <div class="results-box">
                    <p id="vDrop" style="margin: 10px 0;">&nbsp;</p>
                </div>

                <p>Voltage Drop (%)</p>
                <div class="results-box1">
                    <p id="vDropPercent" style="margin: 10px 0;"></p>
                </div>
```

And my javascript:

```js
function printAnswer() {
    var volts = document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_volts")[0].value;
    var amps = document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_amps")[0].value;
    var length = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_m")[0].value);
    var cableSize = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("voltDrop_cableSize")[0].value);
    var ohm = 0;
    var reactance = 0;
    if (cableSize === 630) {
        ohm = 0.0418;
        reactance = 0.08;
    } else if (cableSize === 500) {
        ohm = 0.0506, reactance = 0.082;
    } else if (cableSize === 400) {
        ohm = 0.062;
        reactance = 0.0829;
    } else if (cableSize === 300) {
        ohm = 0.077;
        reactance = 0.0839;
    } else if (cableSize === 240) {
        ohm = 0.0948;
        reactance = 0.0847;
    } else if (cableSize === 185) {
        ohm = 0.123;
        reactance = 0.0862;
    } else if (cableSize === 150) {
        ohm = 0.153;
        reactance = 0.0868;
    } else if (cableSize === 120) {
        ohm = 0.188;
        reactance = 0.087;
    } else if (cableSize === 95) {
        ohm = 0.236;
        reactance = 0.0904;
    } else if (cableSize === 70) {
        ohm = 0.327;
        reactance = 0.0917;
    } else if (cableSize === 50) {
        ohm = 0.471;
        reactance = 0.0962;
    } else if (cableSize === 35) {
        ohm = 0.638;
        reactance = 0.101;
    } else if (cableSize === 25) {
        ohm = 0.884;
        reactance = 0.106;
    } else if (cableSize === 16) {
        ohm = 1.4;
        reactance = 0.111;
    } else if (cableSize === 10) {
        ohm = 2.23;
        reactance = 0.118;
    } else if (cableSize === 6) {
        ohm = 3.75;
        reactance = 0.128;
    } else if (cableSize === 4) {
        ohm = 5.61;
        reactance = 0.137;
    } else if (cableSize === 2.5) {
        ohm = 9.01;
        reactance = 0.143;
    } else if (cableSize === 1.5) {
        ohm = 16.5;
        reactance = 0.157;
    } else {
        msg = "Error";
    }
    var reactanceT = (reactance * length) / 1000;
    var ohmT = (ohm * length) / 1000;

    if (volts < 400) {
        var vDrop = ((ohm * 2) * (length / 1000) * amps);
    } else {
        var vDrop = (Math.sqrt(3)) * amps * (Math.sqrt((Math.pow(ohmT, 2)) + (Math.pow(reactanceT, 2))));
    }


    var vFinal = (volts - vDrop);
    var vDropPercent = ((vDrop / volts) * 100);
    console.log(volts, amps, length, cableSize, ohm);
    document.getElementById("vFinal").innerHTML = vFinal.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("vDrop").innerHTML = vDrop.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("vDropPercent").innerHTML = vDropPercent.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("resistanceCheck").innerHTML = ohmT.toFixed(4);
    document.getElementById("reactanceCheck").innerHTML = reactanceT.toFixed(4);
    
    if (vDropPercent > 3) {

        document.getElementsByName("results-box1").style.color = 'red';
    } else {
        document.getElementsByName("results-box1").style.color = 'green';
    }

}
```

I've looked at similar threads on here and applied what i've found, however i cant get it to work.
The last four lines of the JS code are where i am trying to change the colour based on value, however no matter how hard i try it is not working.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS to make it a [mcve]

Comment: Why not `document.getElementById("vDropPercent").style.color = vDropPercent > 3 ? "red" : "green";`

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of errors:

1. `document.getElementsByName("results-box1")` should be `document.getElementsByClassName("results-box1")` (in the HTML, `results-box1` is the value set for the attribute `class`, not for the attribute `name`)
2. `document.getElementsByClassName("results-box1")` returns a collection therefore it has no `style.color` attribute.

Potential solutions:

- replace `document.getElementsByName("results-box1").style.color` with `document.getElementsByClassName("results-box1")[0].style.color`
- replace `document.getElementsByName("results-box1").style.color` with `document.querySelector(".results-box1").style.color`

Answer (score -2):

`document.getElementsByName` returns a collection of elements. Use `document.getElementsByName("results-box1")[0]` instead for selecting the first element of the returned collection (assuming the first element is the one that you want to change the style). So change your code to

```
if (vDropPercent > 3) {
  document.getElementsByName("results-box1")[0].style.color = 'red';
} else {
  document.getElementsByName("results-box1")[0].style.color = 'green';
}
```